# Pandas - averaging a series of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column called "proficiencies" that is a series of dictionaries (string: float mapping), and I'm trying to calculate the average for each key.

```
CURRENT DATA

{'k': 1, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}
{'k': 0, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}


RESULT I WANT
{'k': 0.5, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}
```

I've checked a couple of answers and it seems that groupby and then aggregating using np.mean is what I need. The problem is I seem to be having trouble with groupby.

This is my code so far - I'm thinking I need to aggregate by the dictionary key and then do a np.mean first (and then divide by length afterwards).

```
df_hypy['proficiencies'].groupby(lambda d: d).aggregate(np.mean)
```

However this throws the error below. Wondering if anyone can help?

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: you are going to have to write this out long-form. `pandas` was not designed to work with `dict`s as values. Just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with converting column `proficiencies` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) + [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html), then [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and last  [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'proficiencies':[{'k': 1, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}, 
                                    {'k': 0, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}]})
print (df)
                      proficiencies
0  {'w': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 0, 'k': 1}
1  {'w': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 0, 'k': 0}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['proficiencies'].values.tolist()).mean().to_dict()
print (df)
{'w': 1.0, 'y': 1.0, 't': 0.0, 'k': 0.5}
```

**Timings**:

```
#[2000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

In [16]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df['proficiencies'].values.tolist()).mean().to_dict())
100 loops, best of 3: 4 ms per loop

#Allen solution
In [17]: %timeit (df.proficiencies.apply(pd.Series).mean().to_dict())
1 loop, best of 3: 453 ms per loop
```

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this using pandas, and your list/array or dictionaries is called `dicts` (in your case, you have `dicts = df_hypy['proficiencies'].values`):

```
dicts = [{'k': 1, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}, {'k': 0, 'w': 1, 't': 0, 'y': 1}]
pd.DataFrame(dicts).mean().to_dict()
```

But this involves creating a DataFrame object, which could be slow. A loop *might* be faster, depending on the amount of data you have:

```
t = dict()
for ele in dicts:
    for key,value in ele.items():
        try:
            t[key].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            t[key] = [value]
{key:np.mean(li) for key,li in t.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'proficiencies': {0: {'k': 1, 't': 0, 'w': 1, 'y': 1},
  1: {'k': 0, 't': 0, 'w': 1, 'y': 1}}})
```

You can probably do something like:

```
df.proficiencies.apply(pd.Series).mean().to_dict()
Out[8]: {'k': 0.5, 't': 0.0, 'w': 1.0, 'y': 1.0}
```